# Why would you loop 'Out' back to 'Vcc'?

Tags: 555

I do not understand the NE556 circuit depicted in this data sheet:
https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/A200/NE-SA-SE556-TI.pdf
on page 6 in figure 1.

[image: NE556 datasheet - figure 1, circuit for astable operation]

More specifically I do not understand why they loop 'Out' back to 'Vcc'. I also don't understand how 'RL'´s resistance will influence the circuit.

I am sorry if this question is trivial in any way. I just don't know where to ask apart from here. Thanks

Comment: "RL" is the "load resistance" which represents the circuit you are attaching the 555 timer to.

Comment: That schematic really should show a connection between the Vcc node and the Vcc pin.

Comment: If 'Vcc' was actually connected to a voltage source I guess attaching the load in-between 'Vcc' and 'Out' rather than 'Ground' and 'Out' would just invert the signal. But 'Vcc' is exclusively attached to 'Out', isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

The "Vcc" terminal of the IC should be connected to the Vcc(5-15V) point at the upper left, as shown in Figure 2 on the datasheet.

Since the 556 output can source or sink current, RL is not needed (but is perhaps shown to suggest how you could connect an external load.)

Answer (score 0):

Connecting RL between VCC and Output pin improves the output high voltage parameter **VOH** .
Reference from TI [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/product/NA555?dcmp=dsproject&hqs=pf#) below
About 1kOhms is mentioned in the datasheet for the specifications.

> Choose RA and C so that RA× C > [maximum normal input high time]. RL
>   improves VOH, but it is not required for TTL compatibility.

VCC should definitely be connected to the 5V - 15V source which is missing in the circuit diagram.